# PHP validating input not working

Tags: php, validation, character-encoding

I've been at this for hours and can't seem to get anywhere.

I'm using `XAMPP` for `Apache 2.0`, `PHP 5.5`, `Chrome` and using `Netbeans` for my editor.

I have an input text box which I want to validate before I use it to search a `MYSQL` database. I use POST to get the input.

The input I'm using is  "x/65!!!"how to

```
 $searchtext = $_POST['searchbox'];
 echo "<br />" . htmlspecialchars($searchtext);
 echo "<br />htmlentitites: " . $searchtext;
 echo "<br />strip slashes : " . stripslashes($searchtext);
 echo "<br />internal encoding is: " . mb_internal_encoding();
```

and my result is:

```
for htmlspecialchars -> "x/65!!!"how to<b>   //why isn't the <b> removed?

for htmlentities     ->    "x/65!!!"how to //shouldn't the forward slash be stripped out?

for stripslashes     ->  "x/65!!!"how to  //shouldn't the '/' be stripped out?

for mb_internal_encoding->  ISO-8859-1 //My php.ini has UTF-8 as the default, I have meta content-type charset="UTF=8" and I though php 5.5 defaulted to UTF8
```

I'm copying from the PHP manual but I'm not getting their results. I suspect it's charset related but I'm not sure where to look anymore.

****Comments********

Jeff,

```
 I changed the spelling of entities and used this string: <b>"'This \!'": /I
```

This is what I get with htmlspecialchars:  "'This !'": /I
and yes, everything is bold. All of my output is bold and I do not get any of

```
       the escape chars showing:  &quot;&quot;&lt;&gt
```

Funny thing is though when I echo $_POST['searchbox']; It comes up without the  but in bold nevertheless.

My mb_internal_encoding() is ISO-8859-1 even though on the beginning of the page I have a meta statement setting it to UTF-8 and for PHP I made the default UTF-8 by removing the semicolon.

I'm beginning to think my PHP interpreter is broken. I'll have to look at XAMPP to see what their recent version is.

Comment: What is the question exactly? If the question is 'how to put this safely into a query', the answer is by preparing or by using e.g. [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).

Comment: note that you're not actually using the `htmlentities` function on this line `echo "<br />htmlentitites: " . $searchtext;` and you spelled it wrong in the echo statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confusing the differences between what these functions do for the source output as opposed to how the browser renders output of that source. make sure you are comparing what you see on screen in the browser with what is shown in the browser's source. you can view the html source code in most popular browsers by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> or [here's a reference for how to do it in a few others](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm).

> for htmlspecialchars -> `x/65!!!"how to<b>`   //why isn't the `<b>`
>   removed?

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) doesn't remove anything, it simply converts certain html characters into their [html entity encoding format](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). So it's translated `<b>` into the html entity `&lt;b&gt;`, which renders on the page as `<b>`. If you look at your source code, it's actually `<br />&quot;x/65!!!&quot;how to&lt;b&gt;`. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to see the `<b>` on screen because it would be interpreted by the browser as an opening bold tag making all your following text bold. this is also why it's not visible in your question because you didn't escape it for the markdown.

> for htmlentities     ->    `x/65!!!"how to<b>` //shouldn't the forward
>   slash be stripped out?

a couple problems here:

- of no real consequence, but I just wanted to point out that you
  spelled it wrong `htmlentitites != htmlentities` in your `echo`
  statement.
- you didn't actually use the
  [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
  function in your code:

  ```
  echo "<br />htmlentitites: " . $searchtext;
  ```

  in order to actually use it, wrap your variable:

  ```
  echo "<br />htmlentitites: " . htmlentities($searchtext);
  ```
- coincidentally enough, even if you had used it, it wouldn't have been
  escaped because regular old forward slash `/` is not an [html
  character
  entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML),
  although it does look very similar to the fractional slash `⁄`, which
  would be encoded as `&frasl;`

> for stripslashes     ->  `x/65!!!"how to<b>`  //shouldn't the `/` be
>   stripped out?

[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) only removes backslashes `\`, and not forward slashses `/`. I think it should have been called `stripbackslashes`, but they didn't ask me :)

> for mb_internal_encoding->  ISO-8859-1 //My php.ini has UTF-8 as the
>   default, I have meta content-type charset="UTF=8" and I though php 5.5
>   defaulted to UTF8

I'm not very familiar with this one, but I can tell you that the default is not `UTF-8`, but is `ISO-8859-1`. are you *sure* that `My php.ini has UTF-8 as the default`? Because my `php.ini` has a line that looks like this: `;mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8` and you should note the semicolon `;` at the beginning means it's commented out. you would have to delete that semicolon, **and restart the web server** to have it take effect.

as for your `meta statement setting it to UTF-8`, I assume you mean you've added an [html meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp) that looks something like `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. this only applies to the html output signaling to browsers what character set to expect, and doesn't have any effect on your internal server settings.

Comment: please see my comments above

Comment: @eric, I have updated my answer. if you don't want to reread the whole thing, then you can [view my changes here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36927036/revisions)

Comment: Jeff, thanks. Once I 'viewed source' for the webpage the string was properly sanitized. I'm giving up on the encoding. My php.ini has default_charset = "UTF-8" (I deleted the semicolon) but I still end up with ISO-8859-1. I do have ;mbstring.internal_encoding = EUC-JP. I tried changing that by removing the semicolon and changing EUC-JP to UTF-8 but that didn't change the default ISO-8859-1. There are too many multibyte settings in the php.ini file for me to mess with (;mbstring.language = Japanese) right now. If I need to then I'll dive into it. Thanks again for all of your help and patience!

Comment: What makes the encoding doubley confusing is that my phpinfo() shows: default_charset UTF-8 for both local and master values. But mb_internal_encoding() still displays ISO-8859-1. *scratches head*

Comment: @eric, did you actually **restart** the web server? you will have to do this in order to reload changes made in the `php.ini`

Comment: Yes, I'm using XAMPP. I restarted apache and looked at php.ini to make sure the semi-colon wasn't there. Still get ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Hmm, that's curious.  well I think that issue might deserve its own question.